# Assistance still needed: SwiftyJSON parsing interpolation(?) Swift enum

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I'm building an app and I can't figure out how to create a "match" from JSON text API given a predefined word; I think this is called interpolation and I think I would have to use enum/switch, but for the life of me I can't figure out how I could implement this with SwiftyJSON.

Basically, I want a user to "win the game" if a predefined word, let's say "apple", matches any of the JSON responses received from the API. If the word is not found in the JSON response then the user will have to keep playing.

Can someone shed some light on this for me on how to go about doing this?

If I'm completely wrong in my methodological assumption please correct me on the proper terms.

I can obviously post my code but it's pretty long and don't want to aimlessly post what I don't need.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I want to match the predetermined word, "apple" to any of the words received from JSON.

If there is a match, the user wins, a message is displayed, the user chooses to progress to the next level or the user returns to the home screen.

If there is no match, the user must either continue playing or cancel playing.

I would like to do this for multiple words across different levels of the game.

Level one: match "apple" to a received JSON response.

Level two: match "computer" to a received JSON response.

Level three: match "telephone" or "phone" or "iPhone" or "Android" or any or all of the above to a received JSON response.

is that more explicit? @rmaddy

there is more to this code but this seems to be the most relevant portion, checking for errors omitted.

```
extension ViewController {

    func analyzeResults(_ dataToParse: Data) {

        // Update UI on the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {


            // Use SwiftyJSON to parse results
            let json = JSON(data: dataToParse)
            let errorObj: JSON = json["error"]

// Check for errors
            if (errorObj.dictionaryValue != [:]) {
                self.labelResults.text = "Error code \(errorObj["code"]): \(errorObj["message"])"
            } else {
            // Parse the response
            print(json)
            let responses: JSON = json["responses"][0]




// Get label annotations
                let labelAnnotations: JSON = responses["labelAnnotations"]
                let numLabels: Int = labelAnnotations.count
                var labels: Array<String> = []
                if numLabels > 0 {
                    var labelResultsText:String = "Labels found: "
                    for index in 0..<numLabels {
                        let label = labelAnnotations[index]["description"].stringValue
                        labels.append(label)
                    }
                    for label in labels {
                        // if it's not the last item add a comma
                        if labels[labels.count - 1] != label {
                            labelResultsText += "\(label), "
                        } else {
                            labelResultsText += "\(label)"
                        }
                    }
                    self.labelResults.text = labelResultsText
                } else {
                    self.labelResults.text = "No labels found"
                }
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Update your question with some brief, relevant JSON and brief, relevant code showing just the parts dealing with your question. Clearly indicate what part you are having trouble with.

Comment: sorry, I thought I was being clear; updated per your request @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

```
let json = JSON(data: dataToParse)

guard json["error"] == nil else {
   print(json["error"].string)
   return
}

let labelAnnonations = response["labelAnnonations"].array
var labels: [String] = []
var labelResultsText = "Labels found: "

if labelAnnonations.count > 0 {

   for labelAnnonation in labelAnnonations {

      labelResultsText += "\(labelAnnonation["description"].string),"
      labels.append(labelAnnonation["description"].string)
   }

} else {

   self.labelResults.text = "No labels found"
}

labelResultsText.remove(at: labelResultsText.index(before: labelResultsText.endIndex))
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I'll try it out. I edited my post to reflect how I check for errors. which way is more efficient/better? @lucaspalaian

Comment: your code looks right but I can't figure out how to implement it in mine above :/ @lucaspalaian